# Как удалить все записи, кроме топ n относительно другого поля?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица такого формата:

```
CREATE TABLE rate
(
    --поля--
    direction        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    rate_main        DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
);
```

Данные выглядят так:

```
direction | rate
1         |  5.9
1         |  1.23
1         |  4.2304
1         |  5.25
1         |  3.06
43        |  74.9
43        |  51.23
43        |  67.2304
43        |  32.25
43        |  1.06
```

С лимитом, например, в `3`, в таблице должны остаться только эти записи:

```
 1         |  5.9
 1         |  5.25
 1         |  4.2304
 43        |  74.9
 43        |  67.2304
 43        |  51.23
```

а остальные удалиться.

Пробовал в этом направлении идти:

```
SELECT rate_main, direction -- DELETE
    FROM rate
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT id
            FROM rate
--          WHERE direction = 4
            ORDER BY rate_main DESC
--          LIMIT 3
    )
    GROUP BY rate_main, direction
    ORDER BY rate_main DESC
```

но не получается.

Comment: Row number с партишеном  в помощь.и удаляет все что выше 3

Comment: Есссно всё это в CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY direction ORDER BY rate_main DESC) rn
              FROM bc_rate )
SELECT *   -- заменить на список нужных полей
FROM cte 
WHERE rn < 4
-- ORDER BY список нужных полей
```

И соответственно удаление:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY direction ORDER BY rate_main DESC) rn
              FROM bc_rate )
DELETE
FROM cte 
WHERE rn > 3
```

Comment: Это более правильный вариант, чем мой?

Comment: @Metamorphosis Ну... да. И не только правильнее, но и должно быть заметно быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [Aziz Umarov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/387032/aziz-umarov)

Сделал так:

```
SELECT rate_main, direction, sub.rating_in_section
    FROM (SELECT rate_main
               , direction
               , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY direction ORDER BY rate_main DESC ) AS rating_in_section
              FROM bc_rate
              ORDER BY direction, rating_in_section, rate_main) AS sub
    WHERE sub.rating_in_section <= 3
    ORDER BY direction, rate_main DESC;
```

Удаление:

```
DELETE
    FROM bc_rate
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT sub.id
            FROM (SELECT id
                       , rate_main
                       , direction
                       , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY direction ORDER BY rate_main DESC ) AS rating_in_section
                      FROM bc_rate
                      ORDER BY direction, rating_in_section, rate_main) AS sub
            WHERE sub.rating_in_section <= top_in
    );
```

Comment: Сортировка в подзапросе не имеет смысла - она всё равно будет проигнорирована, по крайней мере снаружи. А удаление в такой форме... надо пробовать, но будет несколько странно, если выполнится.